# Call a method in mounted - Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, async-await

I am workinf with Vue.js.
I call a method in mounted. But i see this error in console;

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.deneme is not a function**

My code is here:

```js
async mounted() {
    await this.deneme()
}),
methotds: {
    deneme() {
        console.log("it's working")
    }    
}
```

PS: I tried without async/await. But still not working.

Comment: You have a typo. `methotds` instead of `methods`

Comment: sorry , this is a big mistake... i thought it was an async or promise error

Comment: Life cycle hooks are not supossed to be async. At least Vue doesn't await them for you. They can be async as any function, but you may get unexpected behaviour from doing this, since there is no guarantee mounted has finished when you want to use its "results". Additionally, deneme isn't async anyway, so there is no need to await it either.

Comment: Thank you!  this information was very useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo and a closing `)` wrong

[this works](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdD5cbmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IHtcbiAgYXN5bmMgbW91bnRlZCgpIHtcbiAgICBhd2FpdCB0aGlzLmRlbmVtZSgpXG4gIH0sXG4gIG1ldGhvZHM6IHtcbiAgICBkZW5lbWUoKSB7XG4gICAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyhcIml0J3Mgd29ya2luZ1wiKVxuICAgIH1cbiAgfVxufVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge31cbn0ifQ==)

```js
<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.deneme()
  },
  methods: {
    deneme() {
      console.log("it's working")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```